# Texts for a mathematical perspective on dimensional analysis.

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, dimensional-analysis

I am looking for books and papers that take a mathematical perspective on the physics topic of dimensional analysis. I am sure there are such texts out there. I would be very glad to know of any such texts.

Comment: But like, isn't dimensional analysis "easy" in the sense that it's just applying algebra and solving equations?

Comment: Why are you sure of that? The nature of quantities is physical.

Comment: I don't think there is enough content in dimensional analysis to justify a text. It's essentially a consequence of Buckingham's $\pi$ theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem